# In selenium,If we add both implicit(10sec) and explicit wait (5sec) in script then which wait is applicable to element

Tags: selenium

I would like to know ,In selenium,If we add both `implicit(10sec)` and 
explicit `wait(5sec)` in script then which wait is applicable to element

Comment: Do you have a sample application where you have tried this?
Also, there are already answers on StackOverflow that address this issue. i would recommend checking them out and removing this question if your question is already answered.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What if Implicit and Explicit wait, both are used in Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25726897/what-if-implicit-and-explicit-wait-both-are-used-in-framework)

Answer (score 0):

The [**`Documentation`**](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits) clearly mentions :

> Do not mix `implicit` and `explicit` waits. Doing so can cause **`unpredictable wait times`**.
>
> For example setting an `implicit wait` of **`10`** seconds and an `explicit wait` of **`15`** seconds, could cause a timeout to occur after **`20`** seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Either use Explicit OR Implicit Waits, dont use both at once

If you use both then

**our webdriver first will follow the implicit wait and then follow the explicit wait since browser behavior will be sequential like other programing languages due single thread usage.**

Explicit and Implicit Waits
Waiting is having the automated task execution elapse a certain amount of time before continuing with the next step. You should choose to use Explicit Waits or Implicit Waits.

**

> WARNING: Do not mix implicit and explicit waits. Doing so can cause
>   unpredictable wait times. For example setting an implicit wait of 10
>   seconds and an explicit wait of 15 seconds, could cause a timeout to
>   occur after 20 seconds.

**

Read [Selnium DOC](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits)

Answer (score 0):

If you are really in need with Explicit wait (i.e. wait until element to be clickable, invisible etc), you need to add below code above the explicit wait.

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(0);
```

Once done with explicit wait, revert the implicit wait as much wait time you required for further elements. This will avoid cumulative wait time of both implicit and explicit wait.